How do I correct this dynamic translation formula
I am trying to effectively translate English into a made up language of which I made a lexicon in another sheet.
Example:
In sheet 1, column C has about 500 words in the new language. C1 is word1, C2 is word2, etc. In sheet 1, column D has the English translation of the words in the C column. D1 is C1 in English, etc.
In sheet 2 A1, I want to type a paragraph in English, and have it automatically change the words I write in English into the new language words pulled from the lexicon in sheet 1.
Example of desired outcome:
If I type "I am happy" in sheet2 A1, I want A1 to reference sheet1 as a lexicon where D1 would be I, D2 would be am, D3 would be happy, and C1 would be newlangugeI, C2 would be newlanguageam, C3 would be newlanguagehappy. Wherefore, sheet2 A1 would translate itself from "I am happy" into "newlanguageI newlanguageam newlanguagehappy"
It currently works with
=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A1, " "), Sheet1!D2:D1000, Sheet1!C2:C1000, ""))

but does not account for capitalization or punctuation. I am currently trying to fix this formula to address that issue:
=TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1), {".",";",":",",","?","!"}, ""), " "), Sheet1!D2:D1000)), 
    INDEX(Sheet1!C2:C1000, 
        MATCH(TRUE, 
            ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1), {".",";",":",",","?","!"}, ""), " "), 
            TEXTSPLIT(Sheet1!D2:D1000, " "))), 0)
        ),
    TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A1), {".",";",":",",","?","!"}, ""), " ")
))

But I am receiving a value is not available to the formula or function error.

How about sharing some data and expected output?

I got this so far:
=XLOOKUP(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTSPLIT(A45," ",,TRUE,1),",",""),".",""),$A$50:$A$60,$B$50:$B$60,,0)

Where A45 is the English sentence, A50:A60 is the English words, and B50:B60 are the translated words.

(A46 is a TEXTJOIN, so all punctuation is lost.)
